# Norm map and extension of idele class groups

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, adeles

It's a classic fact in class field theory that for an extension of number fields $L/K$, we have the norm map on idele class groups $\mathcal{N}:C_L\to C_K$ descended from the map on ideles given by applying the local norm map at each place, with image $N_{L/K}\in C_K$, which is a closed subgroup and corresponds to an abelian extension etc. etc.

However, there is also a closed embedding $C_K\to C_L$ since $\mathbb{A}_L\cong L\otimes \mathbb{A}_K$ (plus a little more work with general topology/global fields). Hence actually $N_{L/K}\le C_K \le C_L$, so $N_{L/K}$ is a closed subgroup of $C_L$ which is also its image under some quotient. Hence $0\to N_{L,K} \to C_L \to C_L/N_{L,K} \to 0$ actually splits, i.e. $C_L \cong N_{L,K} \oplus C_L/N_{L,K}$. I think everything still applies if we pass to some modulus too.

This seemed kind of weird, but the prospect of working out the consequences of an actual idelic computation were daunting, so I thought I'd ask here. The third terms resembles one side of the Artin reciprocity. Is there a story here? What significance does this have?

Comment: Isn't that third term, $C_L/N_{L/K}$, simply too big, since $C_K/N_{L/K}$ is already the class group?

Comment: Too big for what? I don't mean in the final sentence to actually imply that $C_L/N_{L/K}$ can actually be made to work in the role of a usual class group, just noting a similarity in appearance.

Comment: Okey-dokey, but isn't it more interesting to go in "the opposite" direction, and take a projective limit of $C_K/N_{L/K}$ over larger-and-larger $L$? Maybe I'm not understanding your goals here...

Comment: ?? I'm not sure what you're getting at. I'm familiar with the classical correspondence between the profinite completion and the maximal abelian extension. I'm just asking about whether a not-obviously-related algebraic phenomenon/coincidence has any number theoretic significance. It is kind of a vague/open-ended question, so maybe that's the source of the confusion.

Comment: Ah, ok, ... I guess I don't have anything constructive to say about that particular item, sorry... maybe just thinking about the "class formations" and "Weil groups"... though that's still a bit in the opposite direction of what you suggest. Dunno...

Comment: Could you explain further the sentence "which is also its image under some quotient" ?